# Solve $X_n=\lfloor \sqrt{X_n} \rfloor+X_{n-1}$

Tags: recurrence-relations

How do I solve $X_n=\lfloor \sqrt{X_n} \rfloor+X_{n-1}$? The initial terms are $1,2,3,5,7,10,13,17,21,26,31$. A search on oeis.org/ gave $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor\cdot\lceil n/2 \rceil$ + 1 which should be proven by induction. Is there a different approach?

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas Should be $t-\lfloor \sqrt t \rfloor$.

Comment: You are right! sorry.

Comment: Is this right, or are you computing $X_n$ from $X_{n - 1}$?

Comment: @vonbrand It's correct as it is.

Comment: Why not 1, 2, **4**, **6**, ..., instead of 1, 2, 3, 5, ...?

Comment: @Did As long as the equation holds, I don't care what the values are.

Comment: Sorry but the matter is quite simple: why are you saying that the sequence starts with 1, 2, 3, 5?

Comment: I was working on a TopCoder problem called MagicCandy and found out that those are the initial terms.

Answer (score 0):

The difference equation
\begin{align}
x_{n} = \lfloor \sqrt{x_{n}} \rfloor + x_{n-1}, 
\end{align}
where $x_{0}=1 $ and $x_{1}=2$ can, upon writing out several terms, ie $x_{2}$, $x_{3}$, $x_{4}$, and so on can the given set of values stated. It is without much difficulty to show that the difference equation for $x_{n}$ can also be seen as
\begin{align}
a_{n} = a_{n-2} + n
\end{align}
where $a_{o}=1$ and $a_{2}=2$. The set generated by $a_{n}$ is $a_{n} \in \{ 1,2,3,5,7,10,13,17,21,26,31, \cdots \}$. Now the even and odd values can be considered and yields 
\begin{align}
a_{2n} = n^{2} +1
\end{align}
for $n\geq 0$ for the even case and 
\begin{align}
a_{2n+1} = n^{2} + n+1 = n(n+1) + 1
\end{align}
for the odd case. From the two cases it can readily be sen that the general result is given by
\begin{align}
a_{n} = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor \cdot \left\lceil \frac{n}{2} \right\rceil + 1.
\end{align}

Comment: "It is without much difficulty to show that the difference equation for $x_n$ can also be seen as ...". No doubt about that, but can this be done **without** using induction?